# Struggling with a complex Rails 3 query (need: user.friends.checkins)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a social networking application and am trying to build
a complex query that efficiently pulls all of a users' friends'
checkins from the database.  Basically I need: "user.friends.checkins"

I've recreated (in simplified form) the data structure below for
reference and included several solutions I've found, however I feel
like my solutions are sub-optimal.  I'm hoping that someone can point
out a better way...  So here goes:

I tried this first, which works, but is way too slow given that users
typically have +1000 friends each:

```
=> Checkin.where(:user_id => self.friends)
```

Then I tried this, which also works and is much faster, but feels
sloppy:

```
=> Checkin.joins(:user).joins('INNER JOIN "friendships" ON
"users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id"').where(:friendships =>
{:user_id => 1})
```

Any help you can provide would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks in
advance!!!

**=== Data structure ===**

```
Users table has columns: id, name
Friendships table has columns: user_id, friend_id
Checkins table has columns: id, location, user_id
```

**=== Models ===**

```
class User
 has_many :friendships
 has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
 has_many :checkins
end

class Friendship
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
end

class Checkin
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I've found so far:

```
Checkin.joins(:user => :friendships).where('friendships.friend_id' => self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query should serve you well.  Add indexes to the foreign key fields in the query.

Comment: The problem with the first solution is that it takes 3 seconds to load the 500-1000 ActiveRecord objects that are returned by "self.friends".  It's not SQL that is slow (the SQL only takes 2-3ms), it's ActiveRecord.  I just posted another solution that I've uncovered that seems to be an improvement.